# JavaScript: перебор объекта с учетом сравнения заданного слова

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста как на JavaScript без использования jQuery перебрать содержание HTML внутри `span` в зависимости от количества блоков `div class="column"`?

Другими словами: есть переменная      `var number = 'Один';`. Нужно сравнить ее с содержимым HTML блока  и если есть совпадение, то вернуть весь блок целиком за исключением несоспавших с шаблоном элементов.

Беру цикл:

```
       content = document.getElementsByClassName('column');

        for(var i = 0; i < column.length; i++)
        {
           console.log(column.item(i));
        }
```

В данном случае, цикл выполняется дважды. Получаем два объекта `<div class="column">...</div>`, которые нужно тоже перебрать. Но как?

HTML код:

```
               <div class="column">
                   <div class="category">
                      <div>
                         <h3>
                            <a  href="#">
                            <span>Один</span>
                            </a>
                         </h3> 
                         <h3>
                            <a  href="#">
                            <span>Два</span>
                            </a>
                         </h3>
                         <h3>
                            <a  href="#">
                            <span>Три</span>
                            </a>
                         </h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="colum">
                   <div class="category">
                      <div>
                         <h3>
                            <a  href="#">
                            <span>Четеры</span>
                            </a>
                         </h3> 
                         <h3>
                            <a  href="#">
                            <span>Один</span>
                            </a>
                         </h3>
                         <h3>
                            <a  href="#">
                            <span>Шесть</span>
                            </a>
                         </h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

Спасибо!

P.s. Итогом по маске `var number = 'Один';` должно быть выражение из двух блоков(поскольку и там, и там слово "Один" присутствует):

```
              <div class="column">
                   <div class="category">
                      <div>
                         <h3>
                            <a  href="#">
                            <span>Один</span>
                            </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
              <div class="column">
                   <div class="category">
                      <div>
                         <h3>
                            <a  href="#">
                            <span>Один</span>
                            </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: Приведите пример того, что нужно найти, а то что-то неясно что и в каком виде нужно вернуть.

Comment: @Other Добавил к вопросу!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас вторая рутовая нода имеет класс `colum`, что, вероятно, ошибка.

```js
let word = 'Один'.toLowerCase();

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.column')).forEach(e => {
  // Проверяем все h3 текущего .column на предмет наличия word; если нету - удаляем ноду
  Array.from(e.querySelectorAll('h3')).forEach(e => !e.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(word) ? e.remove() : null);
  
  // Если после проверки контейнер пуст - удаляем ноду (как в случае 3)
  if(e.querySelector('h3') === null)
    e.remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="column">
   <div class="category">
      <div>
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Один</span>
            </a>
         </h3> 
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Два</span>
            </a>
         </h3>
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Три</span>
            </a>
         </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
   <div class="category">
      <div>
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Четеры</span>
            </a>
         </h3> 
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Один</span>
            </a>
         </h3>
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Шесть</span>
            </a>
         </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
   <div class="category">
      <div>
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Четеры</span>
            </a>
         </h3> 
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Пять</span>
            </a>
         </h3>
         <h3>
            <a  href="#">
            <span>Шесть</span>
            </a>
         </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: P.S Не знающим, скрипт в ES6

Comment: @Invision, JS как Творец - един. Так что какая разница-то?

Comment: @Other Спасибо за ответ! Опять придется переводить ваш код в человекопонятный))

Comment: @Pavel, что неясно - спросите, хотя вроде я комментарии написал :)

Comment: @Other подскажите, пожалуйста, а как сделать так, чтобы не трогать текущий html код, чтобы результат фильтра клонировался в другой  `div`? Т.е. вся конструкция вставляется в созданный `<div id="insert"></div>`, а текущие элементы по которым идет сравнение остаются неизменными.

Comment: @Pavel, можно после того, как всё ненужное убилось, взять все `div` через `querySelectorAll` и добавить к нужному Вам `div`'у через обычный `appendChild`.

Comment: @Other  Подскажите, пожалуйста как можно взять весь блок в этом выражении Array.from(e.querySelectorAll('h3')).forEach(e => !e.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(word) ? e.remove() : null);
?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44593/discussion-between-other-and-pavel).